# How to Edit an non-extension Picture?

Tags: file-extension, pictures

I have an open source application that i can edit any files on it. Now i want to edit some pictures that have no Extension! (Just the picture name can shown). and when i open them with any Picture-Editors (like `Paint`, `Ashampoo`, `GIMP`), it says "Unknown Extension.". but i have to Edit this non-Extension picture

**My Question:**
How can i Edit an non-extension picture file?

Comment: What kind of picture? PNG, GIF, JPG, TIFF, etc??? Paint, Ashampoo, and Gimp might not handle that type of image file. Regardless of the extension most editors will use the file header, so this doesn't make sense to me. Can you post the file header or a sample file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, ensure that the file isn't corrupted.

In Linux use [*file*](http://linux.die.net/man/1/file) and in Windows use [**TrID**](http://mark0.net/soft-trid-e.html) to try and determine what format the file is.

Once you've done so you can add the appropriate extension and see if your viewers/editors are able to open it.